# Into what unit does matplotlib dates converts datetime information by date2num?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have some time delta information stored in a DaraFrame.
They look like

```
df.timedelta_last_nms[0:5]
Out: 
0   0 days 00:00:00
1   0 days 00:02:50
2   0 days 00:05:16
3   0 days 00:07:02
4   0 days 00:08:55
Name: timedelta_last_nms, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Plotting this data as x-axis leads to a numbers on the scale of roughly 10^12 or so, which is, I believe, timedeltas in nanoseconds.
Therefore I tried converting the datetime information into numbers, using matplotlib.dates.date2num.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates    
mdates.date2num(df.timedelta_last_nms[0:5])
Out: array([0.        , 1.96759259, 3.65740741, 4.88425926, 6.19212963])
```

The datetime data is successfully converted into scalar numbers (or an array thereof), but the unit remains unclear. It seems like the unit is in the scale of about one to one and half minutes.

However, converting this back into datetime information, yields

```
mdates.num2date(mdates.date2num(df.timedelta_last_nms[0:5]))
Out: 
[datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 2, 23, 13, 20, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 4, 15, 46, 40, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 5, 21, 13, 20, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 7, 4, 36, 40, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)]
```

where the scalar numbers seem to be interpreted as days.

Can anyone tell me, why the conversion units are different between the complementary functions and what the actual unit of date2num is?

Comment: Why don't you add the timedelta column to a date (pd.Timestamp, may be arbitrary), to get a datetime column *before* plotting?

Comment: In general the unit for these functions is days since the epoch, so the output of `num2date` makes perfect sense to me. But I have no idea what is going on with `date2num`, that's weird.

Comment: If you want to plot the actual deltas you could use `df.timedelta_last_nms.apply(lambda x: x.seconds)` to get seconds, then divide by eg 3600 for hours or 86400 for days

Comment: `date2num` as far as I can make out isn't meant to work for timedeltas, and I'm surprised that it doesn't error out

Comment: @JoshFriedlander better: `df["timedelta_last_nms"].dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: @FObersteiner right, good point